# How to open FB session on app launch

Tags: ios, facebook, session

I have an app that includes FB integration (optionally) and this option login occurs in a view controller, which is NOT the root view controller.

It seems to all be working to spec, except that when I relaunch the app the session is closed, whereas, I would like for the session to resume (without having to login every time).  I have tried putting the following code in the viewDidLoad of the root view controller, as well as in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
```

How do you reopen sessions for your users who have previously logged in?

Comment: I should point out that when trying this code in AppDelegate.m, it was limited to a single line that looked like this: [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];

Comment: Another related question: Will this scenario be a problem in iOS6? More, specifically, if I want to limit the FB support to devices running iOS6 will it be easier to maintain an open session across launches?

Comment: How are you handling session state changes callbacks? Are you for example, registering for notifications on state changes and adjusting your UI accordingly? Some more code may help to debug this further. Also with the Facebook SDK 3.1 you should be able to use this method as well and get the added benefit of previous iOS support.